# Trim trailing whitespace tool?

Tags: whitespace

Does anyone know of a command line exe/tool that will **reliably** trim whitespace from the end of lines for the C# language?

Comment: How about a utility written in C#?

Comment: What has the (C#) language to do with the problem? Text is text.

Comment: It is possible for a c# source file to have significant trailing white space -- in string literals, for example.  Is this a concern for you?

Comment: @Henk: It's not safe to do without context in a source code file, for example, one that contains literal multi-line strings (beginning with `@"`)

Comment: @Henk Holterman: C# text is just better. It's yummier.

Comment: @gmaga Good point, that also invalidates my answer below. Never mind.

Comment: The tool would have to be sensitive to C#'s @"" here document.  @RQDQ: a utility written in C# to do this would be adequate as well.

Comment: @OP: may i ask why is the concern? its ok to worry about aspx, but you are worrying about cs. wouldn't a published site solve these probs?

Comment: @lucid: The term "here document" may ring true to someone proficient in some shells or scripting languages, but you will be better understood using the "official" term: *verbatim strings*.

Answer (score 4):

Does it have to be command line? Visual Studio will when you do a `Format Document` (`Ctrl+E+D` or `Ctrl+K+D` depending on keyboard layout).

Comment: I'm fairly sure that Format Document does not remove trailing whitespace it only indents and adds white space after keywords, etc (according to the options that are set).

Comment: @user: ReSharper's code cleanup does remove trailing white space. I'm not sure about Visual Studio's standard formatter, but I think it does too.

Comment: @user: yes, it does remove trailing whitespace. I just tested it again (you had me second-guess myself :-) ).

Comment: Ah hell -- I wonder if this is a setting then.  It would be nice though to batch a whole project and clean up trailing white space instead of having to go through each individual file and run this command.  The same would be true of remove and sort unused using statements.  (I don't want to have to get the full version of VS either to have this feature -- the Express works a large percent of the time).

Answer (score 0):

```
alias trimfile="sed -r 's~[[:space:]]+\$~~g' -i"
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have a little explanation on how to use it